# What is simplest WCF/SOAP configuration?

Tags: wcf, soap

We have a WCF service and I use wsHttpBinding with transport security and custom authentication.

I recently discovered that secure sessions are on by default (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683724/what-are-the-impacts-of-setting-establishsecuritycontextfalse-if-i-use-https)).

I'm surprised that such a feature is on by default. I thought that by default I'd get the simplest configuration and that additional features would be on an opt-in basis.

I want to start with the simplest possible feature set and then decide to opt-in for more features.

So my question is: What are the other features that are enabled by default and how can I turn them off?

Comment: get used to the fact that Microsoft now is "secure by default" in just about all its products.....

Comment: If my understanding is correct, secure sessions doesn't make things more secure; it enables sessions on a secure channel. So I don't this it fits the "secure by default" principle (which is a good principle IMO).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends :-) as per usual.

Do you want to have an externally facing service, that users from outside your network can call into? If so, then use either the `basicHttpBinding` which is basically the same as the legacy ASMX web services (SOAP 1.1, really basic, hardly any security and no reliability features). Or use `wsHttpBinding` (SOAP 1.2, WS-* stuff) from the beginning, but turn off all the features at first.

With the basicHttpBinding, there's no a whole lot to "turn on" later on - you're kinda stuck and need to e.g. switch to wsHttpBinding or create your own custom binding beyond that basic features. wsHttpBinding is pretty heavy-weight, but most of those features like security, reliability etc. can be turn off or back on later. **BUT:** not every client app out there can connect to wsHttpBinding endpoints.

OR: use several endpoints! One really simple one using basicHttp for "legacy" clients, one more advanced with wsHttpBinding - that's the beauty of a WCF service - you write the service code once and expose it on a gazillion different endpoints, as your clients need them!

If you're internal, inside the company firewall the choice is easy - use `netTcpBinding` - it's fast (since it uses binary instead of text encoding) and has lots of features that can be tweaked.

**UPDATE:** since it's an externally facing service, and all kinds of clients might connect, I would use the basicHttpBinding with username/password security:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsMsgSec">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="None" establishSecurityContext="false" negotiateServiceCredential="false"/>
          </security>
          <reliableSession enabled="false"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="YourService">
        <endpoint
            address=""
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="wsMsgSec"
            contract="IYourServiceContract" />
      </service>
    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

For the "clientCredentialType" on the message security tag, you could also use "UserName" - in that case, you would have to set up some infrastructure (e.g. the ASP.NET membership provider system) in order to validate the incoming username/password credentials.

Also, definitely check out the [WCF Security Guidance](http://www.codeplex.com/WCFSecurityGuide) which has step-by-step explanations for a plethora of different security scenarios, and what to do for each in web.config and your WCF config.

Comment: @marc_s: Thank you for your answer. It is an externally facing service so I need security. Our customers and partners invoke the services directly. A sample config file with every feature turned off or set to their minimum (except security) would be very helpful.

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks for the update. You wrote "I would use the basicHttpBinding" but your sample is with wsHttpBinding. I guess you meant "I would use the basicHttpBinding". Correct?

Comment: Oups...I made the same mistake...I guess you meant "I would use the wsHttpBinding". Correct?

Comment: You chose the set negotiateServiceCredential to False. I'm trying to make up my mind about whether I should set it to false (it's true by default and I have the default). I currently use clientCredentialType="UserName". My understanding is that if I set negotiateServiceCredential to False in that context, then my clients will have to manually install my certificate before they can invoke my services. At a first glance I see that as a something that would make my services harder to call. So I don't see the benefits of setting negotiateServiceCredential to False. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, I tried to follow your "turn off everything" mantra :-) But you're right - this requires an out-of-band step before a client call actually call your service - get the service certificate and installing it properly.

Answer (score 1):

wsHttpBinding is a very complex binding built for layering lots of WS-* goo on top of. BasicHttpBinding might be a better place to start- it's just simple SOAP over HTTP- sounds more like what you're after. It's very interoperable, but you can still turn on a lot of WS-* behavior later.

Comment: I need SOAP over HTTPS with custom authentication. Can I implement that with basicHttp?

Comment: Yep- that's exactly what we do. Our auth stuff is built as a behavior that installs a messageinspector to validate.

Comment: @nitzmahone: Would your authentication mechanism work out-of-the-box with any SOAP compliant libraries? Wouldn't the client have to have custom code to pass the credentials to your app? If not, can you please give a little more details on the the authentication process takes place? Thanks a lot

Comment: Probably not- other than WS-Security or HTTP Basic, there's not a lot of "standard" authentication over SOAP out there. You can layer WS-Security on basicHttpBinding, but you haven't specified what kind of authentication you're after. Most SOAP packages make it really easy to add a custom SOAP header to all outgoing requests. We're lucky enough to usually be .NET on both ends, so it's less a concern for us (we do have a corresponding client behavior to do the header injection).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. I guess I'll stick to wsHttpBingin that. Anyways, I think I got the minimal WCF wsHttpBinding configuration figured out now - at least in terms of security settings.

Answer (score 0):

The listing of all the possible attributes of [wsHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731299.aspx) are available - you could go through them and decide which ones you'd like to explicitly set based on your endpoint requirements.