# How does WCF Client retain login session

Tags: wcf, web-services, authentication, wcf-client

I have a WCF client connecting to a WCF Service hosted in IIS via WsHttpBinding with Message level security and UserName client credential type.

In the client, I specify my username and password in an instance of the generated proxy class representing the service. The one proxy instance is used for all subsequent calls, and the service authenticates these credentials in the custom validator either when I explicitly call Open() or when I make my first call on the service. The validation is only made on this initial call, and not on subsequent calls. e.g.:

```
   var client = new MyServiceClient();
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";        client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode =   
X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
    client.GetStuff1(); // authentication is made here
    client.GetStuff2(); // already authenticated, no further authentication. Why/How?
    client.GetStuff3(); // already authenticated, no further authentication. Why/How?
```

How is this session maintained? How can I configure the server and/or client so that authentication is done on each call rather than the "session" that seems to exist? Is this not determined by the `<reliableSession>` which I have off?

The service class is defined with these attributes:

```
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true, AutomaticSessionShutdown = false, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

The client's app.config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="wsHttpBindingWithAuth" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                      <!--
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" /> -->
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://testmachine/MyService.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingWithAuth"
                contract="NewServiceIIS.IMyService" name="wsHttpBindingWithAuth">
                <identity>
                  <certificate encodedValue="ZZZZ" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

This was the source of my frustration and now it is a bliss for you (i.e. you dont need to supply user/pass again)!

Yes, authentication is stored in the `channel`. Once channel opened, the `ClientCredentials` cannot be changed. Channel establishes a security context which is retained within the Channel. With `wsHttpBinding` and message security, this is **username/password which is sent to the server everytime**.

This is by design. The only way to re-authenticate is to close the channel/proxy and create a new proxy.

---

If you wonder what establishing security context is, have a look at [What are the impacts of setting establishSecurityContext="False" if i use https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1683724/what-are-the-impacts-of-setting-establishsecuritycontext-false-if-i-use-https)

Comment: Not sure what "is checked everytime" means. Do you mean every service invoke, or every time the connection is opened? I have a log statement in my custom {UserNamePasswordValidator} class which logs every time Validate() is called. The logs prove that the Validate() call is made only on the initial service call.

Comment: Is establish security context set to true?

Comment: I'm not setting establishSecurityContext, so it is default. The app.config is posed above.

Comment: Try `establishSecurityContext="false"` in `<security mode="Message">`

Comment: It is not necessary to check that in every call. **As I said there is no way you could change it once channel is opened.**

Comment: I'm not looking to change anything when the channel is open. I wanted to know why it was authenticated only initially. You've said that the username and password is sent every time, but I'm not seeing any evidence to support that.

Comment: IT is **sent** everytime but it might not be **checked** everytime. You can check this by looking at the message. it is encrypted, true, but you may examine it. I bet it looks the same on subsequent calls. Remember, the reason it MUST be sent is WS-* standard, the reason it might not be checked is internals of the Microsoft Implementation.