# How to get SoapUI to work with ws-security mode 'TransportWithMessageCredential'

Tags: .net, wcf, soapui, ws-security

I'm trying to create an example request in SoapUI, but i'm not sure how to get it working.

This is a working example in C#:

```
            var myService = new MyServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_MyService");

            myService .ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "User";
            myService .ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";

            var response = myService.MyMethod("parameter1");
```

Configuration:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://myWebsite.com:8000/MyService.svc"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMyService"
          contract="MyService.IMyService" name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

It seems to be that it should not be that hard to get this working in SoapUI, but i keep getting all kind of errors.

Does anyone has a working example for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by disabling 'establishSecurityContext' in the wcf configuration. After doing that, SoapUI is able to make a call.

Configuration:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                establishSecurityContext="false" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://myWebsite.com:8000/MyService.svc"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMyService"
          contract="MyService.IMyService" name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And check the wsa:To box in SoapUI to get it working:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Double click the endpoint information to go into the property of the client endpoint, add Username/password credential and change the WSS-Type to **PasswordText**. As shown below.
[image]
Beside, because of the transport layer security, we are supposed to install the server's certificate in the trusted root certificate authority when the client calls it.
Feel free to let me know If there is anything I can help with.

Comment: I tried this, but i keep getting the following error:  
The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/MyService/GetRequestStatus' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings....  

I did not install the server certificate, is that always required for SoapUI?

Comment: It seems that the soapUI doesn't support this security type of wshttpbinding. so it automatically generate the basichttpbinding  endpoint. on my side, it works when I use basichttpbinding to publish the service. after searching some information on the internet, I still can not make it work. try to refer to the following link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729270/testing-wcf-service-wshttpbinding-with-security-mode-transportwithmessagecreden